I have a problem with nginx proxying. 404 / React.js
It loads my main page - localhost:{port}/
And if I try to go to other endpoints, it gives me a 404 error or doesn’t show it at all.
I need to configure SPA pages somehow, but I have no idea how to do it.
I have two fronts.. But they don’t display endpoints other than main
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /static/ {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location /admin/ {
            proxy_pass http://admin:3001/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3000/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

Frontend / Main

FROM node:18-alpine AS build


WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

RUN npm i sass react-router-dom bootstrap animate.css axios

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


Admin / Panel
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install

RUN npm i sass react-router-dom bootstrap animate.css axios

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


Errors
frontend     | 2024/05/31 15:02:44 [error] 22#22: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/brands" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.32.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /brands HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:3000"
frontend     | 192.168.32.1 - - [31/May/2024:15:02:44 +0000] "GET /brands HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

I'm using front > BrowserRouter
I'm sure the problem is in the configuration itself
